# IFMXDialogServiceSync::InputQuerySync() returns only if press "YES" button in Windows

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder

In C++Builder 10.2.1 I use FireMonkey's [`IFMXDialogServiceSync::InputQuerySync()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDialogServiceSync.InputQuerySync) method to request a string from the user. The message box closes only if I press the `Yes` button, and I can't close this box if I press any other button (`No` or `X`).

```cpp
_di_IFMXDialogServiceSync DialogServiceSync;
if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXDialogServiceSync), &DialogServiceSync))
{
    // ...
    String strIn[1]; strIn[0] = "...some text...";
    String strOut[1]; strOut[0] = "...some text default...";

    String c = "...caption...";
    if (DialogServiceSync->InputQuerySync(c,strIn, 0, strOut, 0))
        ShowMessage("YES!!!");
}
```

I use this code in Windows desktop application.

Comment: I suggest you enable Debug DCUs in your project options and then step into `InputQuerySync()`'s source code at runtime to find out why it is not working correctly. And then [file a bug report with Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: I found same problem in the FireUI App Preview 1.0 when I start this app in Win7 and click on **Advanced...** button: the message box cannot be closed using cancel or **X**